# Should these hyperlinks be encapsulated in a list?

Tags: html

New to html.

In this snippet of html, should the `<a>` tags be wrapped in a list tag of some kind - i.e. an `<li>`?

```
            <div id="site-master-social">
                <span class="strong">Join Us:</span>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="/Images/icon_facebook.png" alt="Facebook" title="Join us on Facebook" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="/Images/icon_twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Join us on Twitter" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="/Images/icon_google+.png" alt="Google+" title="Join us on Google+" /></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: If you want. Then they won't be all on the same line though, unless you use  some CSS tricks. By the way, they are not called tags, they are called elements.

Comment: thanks for the tip Mr Lister

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine.

You can always validate your HTML for correctness here: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Something can be fine. But that does not mean it cannot be better. W3's validator is simply something that looks for errors, and it doesn't not take semantics and usability into account.

Comment: **in this specific case** the person's code is fine and doesn't need to have any **li** encapsulation. It is up to you if you want to build your website using only *div* elements or a variation of others. Just some elements like **li**, **table** or **form** usually have some specific structure you should hang on to.

Comment: I'm not saying that he has to, but I'm saying that the a's belong more together than an a and the span, and a ul can emphasise that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Could be, if you want a list. And then change your outer `<div>` to a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `span` to a `h2` or `h3`, depending on how important it is in the document. `site-master-social` could be an `aside` as well, if you are working with HTML5. I would put the links in a list because semantically they do belong all together but for formatting purposes it is not necessary (but it can come in handy).

Comment: That some things belong together doesn't mean they should be in a list! They are already together in a div.

Comment: @MrLister Of course not, but to make the distinction more clear between the relation between the a's and between the a's and the span (THOUGH their sibling) a list is perfect in this case.